# How to delete an ORIG_HEAD branch in git?

Tags: git, version-control

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [git delete and recreate branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844581/git-delete-and-recreate-branch)

To be honest I'm not sure ORIG_HEAD can be called a branch, yet it appears in my visual editor as one.

I have made a "git reset --hard HEAD~1" and then made some changes, finally committing them. How to get right of that ORIG_HEAD branch?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git delete and recreate branch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11844581/git-delete-and-recreate-branch)

Answer (score 14):

See "[HEAD and ORIG_HEAD in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/964876/head-and-orig-head-in-git)":

> `ORIG_HEAD` is previous state of `HEAD`, set by commands that have possibly dangerous behavior, to be easy to revert them.
>   It is less useful now that Git has reflog: `HEAD@{1}` is roughly equivalent to `ORIG_HEAD`

In your case, you did a `git reset`, so Git left a "reminder" of where you were before said reset.
You can ignore it.

You can also get rid of it with a simple

```
rm -f $GIT_DIR/ORIG_HEAD
# or
rm -f .git/ORIG_HEAD
```

That is what the [`example/git-reset.sh`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/contrib/examples/git-reset.sh#L77-L84) script does for instance.

Comment: Sure, VonC. I know that I can ignore it. But I don't want to have it dangling around. I'd like to get rid of it if possible.

Comment: @devouredelysium I have edited the answer to include a way to get rid of `ORIG_HEAD`

Comment: @powder366 not sure. It is possible the next command which doesn't need to set `ORIG_HEAD` could remove it.